# Get the time show animation how much duration is currntly running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

In jquery i use following code:

```
  j=-(i)
  if(j%2==1)
  {
    $("#caption1").hide();
    $("#caption1").fadeIn(1000);
    $('#main_div').hide();
    $('#main_div').show(5000);
  }
   }
 if(i%2==0)
 {
    $("#caption1").hide();
    $("#caption1").fadeIn(1000);
    $('#main_div').hide();
    $('#main_div').show(5000);
 }
```

while show animation i want the duration of animation completed?

for Example:

i set it show animation for 5secs.

show animation now started.

2 secs animation completed[ 3secs remaining]

in this case i need this completed duration[2secs] on button click??

Comment: Why would the animation complete in 2 seconds when you have it set to 5?

Comment: pls understand 5secs animation started[ 2secs completed  3 secs remaining]

Comment: Ok as far as I understand you want a click event listener after the completion of 2 seconds of show animation ?

Comment: Could you please provide test fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark down the time when the animation started:

```
var animationStarted = new Date();
$('#main_div').show(5000);
....
```

When you need to show how much time has passed, take the current time and subtract the time saved in the previous step.

```
var now = new Date();
var elapsed = ( now.getTime() - animationStarted.getTime() ) / 1000;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NZGU6/

Comment: You can even compute `elapsed` as `now - animationStarted`. valueOf does the rest.